# Adding MPLS Routes in kernel 4.1.3

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, netlink

In Latest Kernel , there is a provision to add mpls routes in kernel, so that kernel can switch the traffic on basis of labels.

I need to write a application from which I can program the MPLS Routes in kernel.
However I don't know how can I do it, I don't have very much experience in Kernel related programming.

I browse the code, Please find some API's -

```
#define PF_MPLS     AF_MPLS
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_NEWROUTE, mpls_rtm_newroute, NULL, NULL);
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_DELROUTE, mpls_rtm_delroute, NULL, NULL);
rtnl_register(PF_MPLS, RTM_GETROUTE, NULL, mpls_dump_routes, NULL);
```

Please help me out. Actually I need a test program written in userspace to configure a MPLS datapath in Kernel.